# Why does key-based ssh fail even after setting up the authorized_keys file on the remote host?

Tags: permissions, ssh

These details don't matter but I am on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine and I want to ssh into my RaspberryPi without a password.  I followed the standard procedure for setting up ssh without a password:

```
local $  ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

(hit enter for defaults to the questions)

```
local $  scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub matt@raspihost:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I logged onto the raspihost and checked all my permissions on `~/.ssh/` and on the `authorized_keys` file itself.  It was *still* not working!

Comment: Looks like I have to wait 8 hours before I can answer this myself.

Comment: Brad, I've moved your answer to a Community Wiki answer, so I can't gain any rep.  You can post the same as an answer, and just ping me my the answer I wrote and I'll remove the Community Wiki'd answer.  Until then, your answer is actually an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> This solution was written by the Original Poster of this question, [Brad Grissom](https://askubuntu.com/users/128609/brad-grissom)

The problem ended up being the permissions of the user directory itself were wide open `777` and they needed to be restricted `755`:

```
raspihost $  ls -lhF /home/
drwxrwxrwx 5 matt matt 4.0K Oct 17 18:24 matt/
raspihost $  chmod 755 /home/matt
```

And now ssh without a password works!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy over the public key. It will ensure all permissions are correct on the remote side and that this issue should never happen.

Use it like you would use `ssh`:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```